# SAS - Custom Date Format - YYYYMMDDhhmmss

Tags: date, sas, format, informat

I need to add a current date to the output I am exporting from SAS in the following format: **filename_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.csv**

I am creating a macro variable the following way:

```
%let date_human = %sysfunc(today(), YYYYMMDDn8.);
```

Does anybody know how to create a custom format for the date I have got? datetime20. gives an incorrect one.

Thank you.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on sas.communities.com last night.

Comment: I cannot find anything that fits my date format, there are some different ones posted, I know. Do you have a link to that post by any chance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the B8601 formats.

```
%let now=%sysfunc(datetime());
%let date_human=%sysfunc(putn(&now,B8601DN8))%sysfunc(timepart(&now),B8601TM6);
```

Answer (score 5):

Two solutions:

**1. Create a picture format with datetime directives using `proc format`**

Here, we are creating a format called `date_human`. You can name this anything that you'd like.

```
proc format;
    picture date_human other='%0Y%0M%0D%0H%0M%0S' (datatype=datetime);
run;

%let date_human = %sysfunc(datetime(), date_human.);
```

**2. Mash together various macro variables**

```
/* YYYYMMDD part */
%let yymmdd   = %sysfunc(today(), yymmdd8.);

%let datetime = %sysfunc(datetime());
%let time     = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(timepart(&datetime.)), time8.0));

/* hhmmss part */
%let hour     = %scan(&time., 1, :);
%let min      = %scan(&time., 2, :);
%let sec      = %scan(&time., 2, :);

/* Put it all together */
%let date_human = &yymmdd.&hour.&min.&sec.;
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! Do you know why am I getting only one digit for HOUR in my date?

2017060895757.csv

Comment: `%let time=%sysfunc(TIME(),time8.0)` would probably be easier than the two step you do, wouldn't it (if you're just trying to get the time part of now)?

Comment: @MaiiaS. Which solution are you going with?

Comment: @Joe, I tried to use %let time=%sysfunc(TIME(),time8.0), but then I get ":"  in the second part of my date, and I need to keep only digits there

Comment: @MaiiaS. You'd still need the scanning bits after that.  I'm just replacing the two `%let datetime ; %let time ;` parts.

Comment: Use `TOD8.` format instead of `TIME8.` to have it add leading zero to the hour. Or use `B8601TM6.` format to eliminate the colons.

Answer (score 0):

Use `picture` in `proc format`:

```
proc format;
    *custom format for the datetime values;
   picture cust_dt other = '%0Y%0m%0d%0H%0M%0S' (datatype=datetime);
run;

** put into macro **;
data test;
    dt = datetime();
    call symputx("dt",strip(put(dt,cust_dt.)));
run;

%put &dt.;

** use macro for filename **;
data file_&dt.; set sashelp.class;
run;
```